# How to solve the complex equation?

Tags: equation-solving, complex

The equation is

$$(1 + i)x = 1 + y i$$

It is a complex equation. I want to directly solve $x$ and $y$. $x$ and $y$ are real.

I tried

```
Solve[(1 + I) x == 1 + I y, {x, y}, x ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals]
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not

```
Solve[{(1 + I) x == 1 + I y, {x, y} ∈ Reals}, {x, y}]
(* {{x -> 1, y -> 1}} *)
```

Comment: This is just what I want

Comment: @tiankonghewo I see you also asked this in Tieba, you should link this post back to avoid people there doing redundant work.

Comment: 你还知道百度贴吧,哈哈,果然是中国人啊

Answer (score 1):

This finds y in terms of x:

```
Solve[(1 + I) x == 1 + y*I]
(*{{y -> I + (1 - I) x}}*)
```

If you want to find x in terms of y:

```
Solve[(1 + I) x == 1 + y*I,x]
(*{{x -> 1/2 (1 + I (-1 + y) + y)}}*)
```

Comment: This can not directly solve x and y at the same time?

Comment: You need 2 equations to solve for 2 variables.

Comment: I understand what you said, but that is not What I want to achieve to.

Comment: Can only do so?

Comment: Yes, if you have 2 variables you generally need two equations. For this problem, no matter what value y takes, you can find an x satisfying this equation and vice versa.

Comment: if so,I know how to do next. thankful